# Compiling .cc file inside a folder at one go

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Currently I have created a working executable program which does something. BUT my problem is that my executable program can only input one `.cc` file at a time by typing

```
fypj@ubuntu:~/build$ bin/lel simple-loops.cc --
```

**Where** `bin/lel` is the executable program **and** `simple-loops.cc` is the file.

Is it possible to add the files inside a folder and allow my program to compile everything inside the folder by just typing the folder name?

**for eg.**

```
fypj@ubuntu:~/build$ bin/lel (folder name) --
```

Comment: Search the internet for "linux for each file directory".

Comment: @thomasmatthews I have tried using BOOST C++ library but that does not work for me.

Comment: How about `for filename in folder/*.cc; do bin/lel $filename; done`?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this is to let the user pass any number of arguments, allowing the use of shell to expand wildcards etc. as required:

```
for (int i = 1;  argv[i];  ++i) {  // N.B. don't start at 0
    processFile(argv[i]);
}
```

Then you can run it with

```
./a.out *.cc
```

to get the behaviour you want.  I'm guessing you don't want to process *every* file (including backup files and `..` etc) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. On Linux, you can use [`opendir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir), [`readdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) and [`closedir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/closedir) to list all the files in a directory. Example:

```
DIR *dir = opendir("name-of-folder");
// if dir is NULL that means the open failed, like with fopen
struct dirent *dirent;
while((dirent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
{
    printf("Found a directory entry: %s\n", dirent->d_name);
}
closedir(dir);
```

Comment: @HiWorld Then pass the thing typed in the terminal to `opendir`, instead of passing it something declared statically?